# zend_oauth_consumer + twitter limit

Tags: zend-framework, twitter

i have a small Twitter App based on Zend_Oath_Consumer.
User gives me a permission to show some statistic about his account.

Due to this page https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting each user should have 350 requests, but actually all users share the 150 Request/hour limit.

Does Zend send unsigned requests? Where can i search for a error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. and it it was my error, as expected...

wrong:
$uri='http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$name;
$client->setUri($uri)

right:
$uri='http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json;
$client->setUri($uri);
$client->setParameterGet($uri,array("screen_name"=>$name));

%&$§/&%! <-untranslatable swearword....

Answer (score 1):

Check your response headers from twitter for:

```
X-Warning: Invalid OAuth credentials detected.
```

based on:

> Ensure you inspect the headers returned when requesting methods which
>   do not require authentication. If the request you make includes
>   invalid *OAuth information* the API will do one of two things:
>
> **For methods which require authentication**, the API will return an error
>   response with more information about the error. *For example an HTTP
>   401 error with the response body Could not authenticate with OAuth.*
>
> **For methods which can be requested unauthenticated,** the API will
>   process the request as if authentication had not been used. This means
>   the request will count against the unauthenticated rate limit. If this
>   has happened the API will include the following header in it's
>   response: *X-Warning: Invalid OAuth credentials detected.*

I suspect your problem has more to do with an Oauth mismatch then anything else. the [Obtaining access tokens](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens) page may be of some help.

Comment: no x-warnings in header. verify_credentials gives information about logged in user. recreate the app doesn't help...